# When iframe is clicked it loads the page it is displaying

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I am trying to make it so when you click on an iframe it loads the page it is displaying. I have tried putting it inside a `<a href="blaa.com"><iframe src="something.com"></iframe></a>` tag but that does not work. I want an effect much like [zoomer](http://github.hubspot.com/jquery-zoomer/) were when your mouse clicks on the iframe it sends you to the source page. This effect would require the iframe to not allow selection of its text. I tried putting a layer above the iframe of the same size and having that link but this does not work because of what this iframe will be doing.

**EDIT:**
The iframe is on the same domain

Comment: Is the iframe on same domain?

Comment: @Johnツ Yes, I shall add that.

Comment: Make a fiddle at : http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @TheDarkKnight I would not think a jsf would be necessary because the only thing that is different from any other iframe is that this iframe is moving around in a carousel so the linking has to be done via the iframe not some other element.

Comment: @Joren That is not the case. That question was answered by the answerer giving the op a different way to do what he needed without an iframe(The op wanted to trim down an image and for some weird reason was using an iframe to do it). I need this to be an iframe. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: @NoahHuppert can't you use Zoomer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok third try: The magic of javascript

jQuery has a method, called .contents() , that when used on an iframe element returns the document of the iframe.

```
// Get a reference to the iframe document
var iframeDoc = $('#inviteFrame').contents().get(0);
```

Now you can bind a click event to it:

```
// Bind event to iframe document
$(iframeDoc).bind('click', function( event ) {
  // User has clicked the Iframe !!
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make the entire page inside the iFrame a link with target _top, but only if the url is page.(html/php)#iframe

Comment: I with that would work. The problem is I am linking to a physical blog post that already exist. It wouldn't be that user friendly if the reader clicked on the post text(on the post viewing page) and got relinked back to it.a Thanks for trying though.

Answer (score -1):

Oh, I see. Why not just an image of the page that goes to the actual page, instead of an iframe?

Comment: This is going to be used on a blog. The 5 most recent posts are on a carousel that is rotating around. Instead of taking up a lot of space with thousands of images I am just going to show the article. A Lot more efficient and all around better.

Comment: thats debatable since it will result in many more file requests on the server then if you would just load images there, it will also mess around with traffic measurement

Comment: @Hannes I honestly do not see my webpage getting more than 30 views a month(and my hosting plan has a limit of 3 million) so if thats 5 frames per visit and 30 visits thats a total of 150 views which is far less than my limit. The only other thing to do would be to make a script that somehow takes a screenshot or something of the webpage and puts the link for it in a database. Is that possible?

Comment: @Noah Huppert - possibile yes, but not really worth the effort. There are services that offer this for free ( limitations to maximal image size, requests and /or with a watermark – but it may be worth goggling for). And to the point - even if it does not matter for the overall traffic it means that everybody who visits the page has to load the page 5 times at the same time which will probably be not the best UserExperience